# react leaflet map disables ant design select

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, antd, react-leaflet

Im using leaflet maps in a react application.
it is great but when I created a card the overlays the map, it is click-through, this means that if I double click the card, it zooms in the map. this is not good. [so after some searching](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104507/disable-panning-dragging-on-leaflet-map-for-div-within-map) - found the solution, I added `L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation` and it works like a charm!

But not I have a new problem, the `Select` component from Ant Design doesn't work, (I know that the dropdown from Material UI does work even with disableClickPropagation).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use card overlays. They are essentially work arounds. You can try to render your control as a Maplayer